# Не работает register_next_step_handler при использовании webhook

Tags: telegram-bot, telegram, telebot

Не работает `bot.register_next_step_handler()` при установленном webhook.
Если убрать webhook и использовать `bot.polling()` то все работает.

Webhook Info:

```
{"ok":true,"result":{"url":"https://my_domain.com/<my_token>","has_custom_certificate":false,"pending_update_count":0,"max_connections":1}}
```

Инициализирую так:

`bot = telebot.TeleBot("<token>", threaded=False)`

Answer (score 1):

Вставьте в ваш код такую конструкцию

```
bot.enable_save_next_step_handlers(delay=2)
bot.load_next_step_handlers()
```

Взято из официальной документации [отсюда](https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI/blob/master/examples/step_example.py)

У меня все начало работать на вебхуках, после вставки данных строк. Желаю вам успехов!