# Есть ли у pyTelegramBotAPI аналог ConversationHandler из python-telegram-bot?

Tags: python, telebot

В библиотеке [python-telegram-bot](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/blob/master/tests/test_conversationhandler.py) есть функция ConversationHandler. Есть ли подобное в библиотеке [pyTelegramBotAPI](https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI)

К примеру как из этого...:

```
from telegram import Bot
from telegram import Update
from telegram import ReplyKeyboardMarkup
from telegram import ReplyKeyboardRemove
from telegram import ParseMode

from telegram.ext import Updater
from telegram.ext import CommandHandler
from telegram.ext import MessageHandler
from telegram.ext import Filters
from telegram.ext import RegexHandler
from telegram.ext import ConversationHandler
from telegram.ext import CallbackQueryHandler

from config import TG_TOKEN
from db2 import create_or_update_list, get_user
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

def anketa_start(bot, update, user_data):
    update.message.reply_text("Как тя звать?", reply_markup=ReplyKeyboardRemove())
    return "name"

def anketa_get_name(bot, update, user_data):
    # my_keyboard = ReplyKeyboardMarkup([['/billy', '/start'],['Заполнить анкету']])
    user_name = update.message.text
    if len(user_name.split(" ")) !=2:
        update.message.reply_text("Введите имя и фамилию")
        return "name"
    else:
        user_data['anketa_name'] = user_name
        reply_keyboard = [["1","2","3","4","5"]]
        update.message.reply_text("Ваша оценка боту?", reply_markup=ReplyKeyboardMarkup(reply_keyboard, one_time_keyboard=True, resize_keyboard=True))
        return "rating"

def anketa_rating(bot, update, user_data):
    user_data['anketa_rating'] = update.message.text
    update.message.reply_text("Введите пожелание или /cancel")
    return "comment"

def anketa_comment(bot, update, user_data):
    my_keyboard = ReplyKeyboardMarkup([['/billy', '/start', 'ToNews'],['Заполнить анкету', 'Watchin U']])
    user_data['anketa_comment'] = update.message.text
    user_text = """
<b>Имя Фамилия:</b> {anketa_name}
<b>Оценка:</b> {anketa_rating}
<b>Пожелание:</b> {anketa_comment}""".format(**user_data)
    update.message.reply_text(user_text, reply_markup=my_keyboard, parse_mode=ParseMode.HTML)
    return ConversationHandler.END

def anketa_skipcomment(bot, update, user_data):
    my_keyboard = ReplyKeyboardMarkup([['/billy', '/start', 'ToNews'],['Заполнить анкету', 'Watchin U']])
    user_data['anketa_comment'] = update.message.text
    user_text = """
<b>Имя Фамилия:</b> {anketa_name}
<b>Оценка:</b> {anketa_rating}""".format(**user_data)
    update.message.reply_text(user_text, reply_markup=my_keyboard, parse_mode=ParseMode.HTML)
    return ConversationHandler.END



def talk_to_me(bot, update):
    chat_id = update.message.chat_id
    if chat_id == 0000000000 or chat_id==0000000005: # 
        user_text = "Привет {}. You wrote [{}]".format(update.message.chat.first_name, update.message.text)
        reversed = "Перевёрнуто будет так : {}".format(update.message.text[::-1])
        update.message.reply_text(user_text)
        update.message.reply_text(reversed)
    else:
        update.message.reply_text("Ухади")
        print(chat_id)

def dontknow(bot, update, user_data):
    update.message.reply_text("IDK!")


def main():
    mybot = Updater(token=TG_TOKEN)
    dp = mybot.dispatcher
    dp.add_handler(CommandHandler('start', hello_user))
    dp.add_handler(CommandHandler('billy', billy))
    dp.add_handler(RegexHandler('^(ToNews)$', show_inline)) #show_inline

    mybot.job_queue.run_repeating(tonews, interval=900)



    anketa = ConversationHandler(
    entry_points=[RegexHandler('^(Заполнить анкету)$', anketa_start, pass_user_data=True)],
    states={
    "name": [MessageHandler(Filters.text, anketa_get_name, pass_user_data=True)],
    "rating": [RegexHandler('^(1|2|3|4|5)$', anketa_rating, pass_user_data=True)],
    "comment": [MessageHandler(Filters.text, anketa_comment, pass_user_data=True),
                CommandHandler('cancel', anketa_skipcomment, pass_user_data=True)]
    },
    fallbacks=[MessageHandler(Filters.text, dontknow, pass_user_data=True)]
    )


    dp.add_handler(anketa)


    dp.add_handler(MessageHandler(Filters.text, talk_to_me))

    mybot.start_polling()
    mybot.idle()




if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

...Сделать telebot версию?

Answer (score 1):

Да, есть. Делается это через types. Отдельное спасибо [данному вопросу](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1033597/%D0%9D%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-register-next-step-handler-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-webhook) и [ответчику](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/240529/%D0%9A%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BB-%D0%9B%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2).

К примеру ([credits](https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI/blob/master/examples/step_example.py)):

```
"""This Example will show you how to use register_next_step handler."""

import telebot
from telebot import types

API_TOKEN = '<api_token>'

bot = telebot.TeleBot(API_TOKEN)

user_dict = {}


class User:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.age = None
        self.sex = None


# Handle '/start' and '/help'
@bot.message_handler(commands=['help', 'start'])
def send_welcome(message):
    msg = bot.reply_to(message, """\
Hi there, I am Example bot.
What's your name?
""")
    bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, process_name_step)


def process_name_step(message):
    try:
        chat_id = message.chat.id
        name = message.text
        user = User(name)
        user_dict[chat_id] = user
        msg = bot.reply_to(message, 'How old are you?')
        bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, process_age_step)
    except Exception as e:
        bot.reply_to(message, 'oooops')


def process_age_step(message):
    try:
        chat_id = message.chat.id
        age = message.text
        if not age.isdigit():
            msg = bot.reply_to(message, 'Age should be a number. How old are you?')
            bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, process_age_step)
            return
        user = user_dict[chat_id]
        user.age = age
        markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(one_time_keyboard=True)
        markup.add('Male', 'Female')
        msg = bot.reply_to(message, 'What is your gender', reply_markup=markup)
        bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, process_sex_step)
    except Exception as e:
        bot.reply_to(message, 'oooops')


def process_sex_step(message):
    try:
        chat_id = message.chat.id
        sex = message.text
        user = user_dict[chat_id]
        if (sex == u'Male') or (sex == u'Female'):
            user.sex = sex
        else:
            raise Exception()
        bot.send_message(chat_id, 'Nice to meet you ' + user.name + '\n Age:' + str(user.age) + '\n Sex:' + user.sex)
    except Exception as e:
        bot.reply_to(message, 'oooops')


# Enable saving next step handlers to file "./.handlers-saves/step.save".
# Delay=2 means that after any change in next step handlers (e.g. calling register_next_step_handler())
# saving will hapen after delay 2 seconds.
bot.enable_save_next_step_handlers(delay=2)

# Load next_step_handlers from save file (default "./.handlers-saves/step.save")
# WARNING It will work only if enable_save_next_step_handlers was called!
bot.load_next_step_handlers()

bot.polling()
```